# How to avoid not used function to be wiped out by optimizer

Tags: swift, linker, llvm

While compiling and Xcode swift project for MacOS, not used functions are removed from the binary (removed by the optimizer I guess). Is there a way to tell the compiler to not remove unused functions, perhaps with a compiler option (`--force-attribute`?) so that even with optimization enabled those functions remain in the binary?

I know that if a global function is declared as `public` (`public func test()`) then it's not removed even if not used (Since it can be used by other modules), but I can't use `public` since that would export the symbol for that function.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's your use-case? If a function is not used and not exported, it seems a bit pointless having it. Maybe there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @JeremyP calls to that function are injected afterward, once the project is built by a separate tool.

Comment: @fjanisze, I haven't tried this but I think it's likely to work.  Let's say you have a function `func foo() -> String`.  You could create a variable (maybe even a `fileprivate` global, like `var unusedFooPtr = { foo() }`.  Being a global, I don't think Swift will give you any warnings about its not being read from, and being a `var` I don't think the optimizer will eliminate it, which I suspect it would do for a `let` variable.

Comment: You could also try a pair of otherwise unused functions that call each other, but also call the function you want don't want eliminated.  So `func fooKeeper1() { _ = foo(); fooKeeper2() }` and `func fooKeeper2() { fooKeeper1() }`

Comment: @ChipJarred The issue with those approaches is that they involve calling the function but that should not happen outside the places where the call is injected afterward :/ So basically I've this void function that is there doing nothing, a tool p rocess the binary after compilation and add calls to that function in magic places, those calls are fine but any other is not fine

Comment: @fjanisze, I'm not clear why that would matter if the functions that call it are never called.  They are just there to prevent the function from being eliminated, so I wouldn't think they would interfere with anything, but I don't know your post-build tool.  You could try assigning the function (not a call to it) to a variable (`var fooKeeper = foo`).  If there's only one function with that name, that assignment doesn't present a problem, but if there are overloads, or it's generic, you'll have to help the compiler out a bit by specifying an appropriate type for `fooKeeper`.

Comment: BTW - there is a linker option for "Dead Code Stripping" (click on your project -> Build Settings -> All -> Linking).  For me it's set to "No", but it's worth checking in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed removed by the optimiser, then the answer is two-fold.

The optimiser removes only things that it can prove are safely removable. So to make it not remove something, you remove something that the optimiser uses to prove removability.

For example, you can change the visibility of a function in the .bc file by running a pass that [makes the functions externally callable](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalValue.html#a687973de03d041e04b50a76d19d4fd36). When a function is private to the .bc file (also called module) and not used, then the compiler can prove that nothing will ever call it. If it's visible beyong the .bc file, then the compiler must assume that something can come along later and call it, so the function has to be left alive.

This is really *the* generic answer to how to prevent an optimisation: Prevent the compiler from inferring that the optimisation is safe.

Writing and invoking a suitable pass is left as an exercise for the reader. Writing should be perhaps 20 lines of code, invoking… might be simple, or not, it depends on your setting. Quite often you can add a call to [opt](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) to your build system.

Comment: But isn't making the function externally callable (manipulating the llvm ir) the same as declaring it `public` in the swift source code? I suggested in my question that I cannot allow the function to be exported, so that it remains private for the module.

Comment: If you make a function `public` in the source code, then it can be used in the way you don't want. If you make it public in-RAM during compilation (long after the access checks) but never change the source, then it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered, the solution here is to use a magic compiler flag `-enable-private-imports` (described [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/include/swift/Option/Options.td): "*...Allows this module's internal and private API to be accessed*") which basically add the function name to the list `@llvm.used` that you can see in the bitcode, the purpose of the list is:

> If a symbol appears in the @llvm.used list, then the compiler,
> assembler, and linker are required to treat the symbol as if there is
> a reference to the symbol that it cannot see (which is why they have
> to be named)

(cit.) As described [here](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#the-llvm-used-global-variable).

This solves my original problem as the private function even if not used anywhere and not being public, during compilation is not stripped out by the optimiser.